# R Identify( ) function

Tags: r, data-analysis, scatter-plot

From UBSprices data set in arl4 package, check below. I wanted to get the cities with the highest increase or decrease in BigMac price (2003 vs 2009).

```
head(data.frame(row.names(UBSprices),bigmac2009,bigmac2003),5)
  row.names.UBSprices. bigmac2009 bigmac2003
1            Amsterdam         19         16
2               Athens         30         21
3             Auckland         19         19
4              Bangkok         45         50
5            Barcelona         21         22
```

I had tried `plot()` and `idenitfy()` function, but the program is not running, and not until I terminate it that I would be able to do any other thing in the console. The below is the code I tried.

```
plot(bigmac2003, bigmac2009)
identify(bigmac2003, bigmac2009, labels = rownames(UBSprices),plot = TRUE)
```

AND

```
plot(bigmac2003, bigmac2009)
identify(bigmac2003, bigmac2009, labels = row.names(UBSprices))
```

Kindly help. Thanks

Comment: output of `dput(UBSprices)` helps us to think about your data

Comment: @SametSökel. The above  is the first 5 rows of the data

Comment: Just sort them with `order`? Perhaps just `UBSprices[order(UBSprices$bigmac2003 - UBSprices$bigmac2009),]`, and you pick the top `n` rows you want.

Comment: You asked how to *"get the cities with the highest increase or decrease"*, but you tagged with [tag:scatterplot] and say you tried `plot(.)`, so I'm confused what you are trying to do here. Is it that you want to *plot* the prices, and somehow highlight which of those prices is among the top `n`-most changed?

Comment: @r2evans, I basically want to find which cities have the highest increase or decrease. I was told that `identify ( )` and `row.names( )` would be useful in this case. When I browse identify () online, It was usually used it with `plot( )`.   That's why I used the two together. Please just help me get my initial want - **getting cities with the highest increase or decrease in price using `idenfity( )` and `row.names( )`**

Comment: `identify` is an interactive-only tool, so it relies on *you* visually identifying points on a plot and it returns the nearest points in the data; this is not a programmatic approach. And because it is human-interactive, it is a flawed approach to use to find something as basic as "highest increase or decrease". This is a unimodal decision: increase/decrease is based on the arithmetic subtraction of two numbers, and the "highest" is found by ordering the differences. `plot` helps visualize it, but it does not calculate it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @r2evans. I have actually thought of this, and I have implemented your initial comment. Remain blessed.